# what is the most similar queue service in Azure to Aws SqS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-sqs

i am using AWS SqS and as part of migration to Azure i am testing Azure testing Azure queue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage and also rabbitmq https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html . the  App is in python so what is the most similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many alternative available, i would recommend you to use [`Service bus queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/).

```
from azure.servicebus import QueueClient, Message
```

## Create the QueueClient

```
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string("<CONNECTION STRING>", "<QUEUE NAME>")
```

## Send a test message to the queue

```
msg = Message(b'Test Message')
queue_client.send(msg)
```

Here is the documentation on how to get started with **[python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues)**.